# python Merge Sort without using the slice method

Tags: python

I'm trying to use def split for slicing the list in mergesort. What am I doing wrong? Does my def split have any issues? Please help!!!

I'm trying to use def split for slicing the list in mergesort. What am I doing wrong? Does my def split have any issues? Please help!!!

```
def split(alist, start, end):
    result = []
    if not(0 <= start < len(alist)):
        return result
    elif not(start <= end < len(alist)):
        return result
    else:
        for i in range(start, end):
            result.append(alist[i])
        return result

def mergeSort(alist):
    print("Splitting ",alist)
    if len(alist)<=1:
        return alist
    elif len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        start = 0
        end = len(alist)-1
        lefthalf = split(alist,start,mid)
        righthalf = split(alist,mid,end)
        
        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] <= righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
    print("Merging",alist)

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
mergeSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

Comment: It appears that your definition of `split` is inclusive of `start` and exclusive of `end`.  So in your `'mergeSort` function, you need to set `end` to `len(alist)`, not `len(alist) - 1`.

Comment: You also realize that Python will let you do the splits as `lefthalf = alist[:mid]` and `righthalf = alist[mid:]`, and you don't need to write your own splitter, right?